# HttpURLConnection reset by peer on first run...works on immediate rerun

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection, java-io

So i have some code which i am using to read a text file from a url. However it is showing some strange behavior. The first time i run the code i recieve a connection reset by peer error and all of the code does not run.

If i then rerun the code immediately there after the code runs fine, file is downloaded and operations are performed as intended.
Here is the code:

```
public static String GetMasterFileStream(String Operation) throws Exception {
    System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedWriter bw = null;
    String inputLine = null;
    System.out.println("Server manifest checks starting");

    URL url = new URL(CrewAdviceMasterControlURL);
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    con.setRequestProperty("connection", "close");

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));


    File outfile = new File(LocalManifestFile);

    String return_string = "";
    String [] ManifestLines;


       switch (Operation) {
        case "PreCheck":
            inputLine = in.readLine();
            sb.append(inputLine.toString());
            return_string = String.valueOf(sb);
            break;
        case "UpdateMaster":
        case "CreateMaster":

            if(!outfile .exists()){
                outfile .createNewFile();
            }
            FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(outfile);
            bw = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);
            int endlinecount =0;
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(inputLine);   //for producing test output
                sb.append(inputLine.toString());
                sb.append("\n");
                if (endlinecount > 0)
                {
                    bw.write("\r\n");
                }
                bw.write(String.valueOf(inputLine));
                endlinecount++;
            }
            bw.close();
            System.out.println("Manifest file successfully written...");

            return_string = String.valueOf(sb);
            ManifestLines = return_string.split("\n");
            return_string = ManifestLines[0];
            //text = text.replace("\n", "").replace("\r", "");
            break;
         }
    in.close();

    return return_string;
}
```

Here is the error logs:

```
W/System.err: java.net.SocketException: recvfrom failed: ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer)
D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 6333K, 33% free 18277K/26880K, paused 50ms, total 50ms
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.maybeThrowAfterRecvfrom(IoBridge.java:545)
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.recvfrom(IoBridge.java:509)
W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:489)
W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.access$000(PlainSocketImpl.java:46)
W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketInputStream.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:241)
W/System.err:     at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:162)
W/System.err:     at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fillbuf(BufferedInputStream.java:142)
W/System.err:     at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:227)

W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.Util.readAsciiLine(Util.java:316)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RawHeaders.fromBytes(RawHeaders.java:320)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpTransport.readResponseHeaders(HttpTransport.java:147)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:795)
 W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:347)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:296)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:179)
W/System.err:     at com.cm3.danielhutchinson.lialpatools.CrewAdviceFunctions.GetMasterFileStream(CrewAdviceFunctions.java:60)
W/System.err:     at com.cm3.danielhutchinson.lialpatools.CrewAdviceFunctions.PreCheck(CrewAdviceFunctions.java:179)
W/System.err:     at com.cm3.danielhutchinson.lialpatools.CrewAdviceActivity$AdviceController.doInBackground(CrewAdviceActivity.java:210)
W/System.err:     at com.cm3.danielhutchinson.lialpatools.CrewAdviceActivity$AdviceController.doInBackground(CrewAdviceActivity.java:176)
W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
W/System.err: Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: recvfrom failed: ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer)
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.Posix.recvfromBytes(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.Posix.recvfrom(Posix.java:141)
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.recvfrom(BlockGuardOs.java:164)
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.recvfrom(IoBridge.java:506)
W/System.err:   ... 23 more
```

Comment: 'con.setRequestProperty("connection", "close");'. Why? Remove that line.

Comment: 'PreCheck'. You did tell nothing of that. Why not? Is it involved?

Comment: okhttp in your logcat. How is that possible with UrlConnection?

Comment: @greenapps to answer your question i pass the operation command when calling the method.

Comment: @greenapps to answer your question i pass the operation command when calling the method. 

Precheck is called under a specific circumstance. Basically precheck reads the first line of the text file and returns only that line. That line contains a time stamp. The stamp is then compared to the time stamp of a file stored locally. If the server stamp is greater than the local stamp then i know there has been a update of the content of the server. So i can then start downloading the rest of the manifest file which in turn tells which file to update locally.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that in testing the connection was reset by the server 50% of the time on the first try and would always work on immediate retry.

When i had tested this code previously it never happened. Further research lead me to believe this could be a glitch on the server side that was not always present.

I fixed  the problem by basically putting the code inside a while loop keyed to a "success flag".

If the code throws the connection reset error then the connection is retried. If it is successful, no retry and i then put in a retry counter which after 3 retry attempts would exit the loop and alert he user to a server error. So far success rate on the 2nd attempt is always 100%.